# Выделение дескриптора GCHandle для передачи указателя на структуру

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, interop

Можно ли таким способом безопасно выделять дескриптор под объект, вернуть указатель на структуру, далее произвести вызов неуправляемого кода передав ему этот указатель, и гарантированно освободить этот дескриптор, при этом реализацию передачи структуры скрыть от пользователя, что бы не баловался?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    ...

    public static unsafe IntPtr AsPtr(this RPoint point, out GCHandle handle)
    {
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(point, GCHandleType.Weak);
        return new IntPtr(&point);
    }
}
```

Пример вызова неуправляемого кода:

```
bool DrawPoint(RPoint point)
{
    GCHandle handle;
    IntPtr handlePoint = point.AsPtr(out handle);
    int result = As<RenderDrawPoint>().Invoke(Handle, handlePoint); // Вызов будет примерно такой, через вытягивание делегата на неуправляемую функцию
    handle.Free();
    return result == 0;
}
```

Comment: А что вы таких хитро пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Кстати, у вас AsPtr возвращает указатель на локальную переменную - так делать нельзя.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Дескриптор же выделен, все должно быть нормально. А пытаюсь передать указатель на структуру в неуправляемый код, дабы не производить копирование памяти и ее освобождение.

Comment: вы выделили дескриптор на копию структуры в куче, а передали указатель на параметр в стеке. Ну и, вообще-то, дескриптор у вас не запинен.